# Ruby on Rails: Get next item in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, models, scaffold

Say I have simply ran `rails g scaffold book name:string about:text` On the 'show' view, how would I implement a button to go to the next item in the model.

I can't simply do `@next = @book.id + 1` because if `@book.id = 2` (for example) and I clicked destroy on the book with an id of 3. It would result in a broken page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do:

```
 @next = Book.first(:conditions => ['id > ?', @book.id], :order => 'id ASC')
```

Remember to check whever @next is not nil

To be even cooler, you can create a method in your model like so:

```
def next
  Book.first(:conditions => ['id > ?', self.id], :order => 'id ASC')
end
```

then if you have @book you should be able to invoke it like

```
@book.next
```

haven't written anything in RoR recently but this looks reasonable to me;)

Comment: And I was about to do this: http://duanesbrain.blogspot.com/2008/11/ruby-on-rails-get-next-activerecord.html