# Rails / design array issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my 'releases' show view I have the following code:

```
<% i = @release.id %>
<%= link_to image_tag('next.png'), release_path(i+1), :class => "editRelease" %>
```

Which takes the user to the next result in the releases table.

I am hoping to only display this 'next' button if an item exists in the array whose id value is one greater than the current release.

Happy to re-write this section of the view / place code in model,controller,helper definition. 
Just trying to learn the correct rails way to solve this issue!

Thank you!

Comment: Define "next"; ids need not be strictly sequential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Records can be deleted, leaving gaps in your range of ID's, as such using a direct `id+1` could point to a null record.

Instead you should define a `next` method in your model that safely returns the next object. If you don't have any ordering then you can use a query like the [one posted in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7209945/385532)

Comment: The only issue I can see with the linked solution is that it makes three calls to the server... Is there anyway of condensing this into one call?